# XQuartz X11 2.7.5 not found

Tags: x11

to get X11 i went to XQuartz here https://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.5
however the download linke XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg seems to be broken -- couldn't find it anywhere else either. what am i missing?

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [XQuartz home page](https://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) you will find a link to download XQuartz that should be correct.

If you are running OS X 10.9 then you need version 2.7.5

At the moment it is http://xquartz.macosforge.org/downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg but our friends at MacOSforge appear to have a broken server. The problem is not yours, it is on their system.

Wait a few more hours and it should be right.

If you can't wait then grab it from my dropbox :-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6c2owdu0nkf7aa/XQuartz-2.7.5.dmg

(note to everyone - I'll remove it in a day or so. Try the website first.)

Comment: thanks for your help. indeed a link that was broken yesterday is working today.

Answer (score 0):

Xquartz should also be available through homebrew and macports,  although I am unsure of the versions available in each.

Answer (score -2):

XQuartz is available in MacPorts as the default X11 server (xorg-server).